# Docker doesn't recognize the -p command all of a sudden

Tags: docker

So I just updated Docker on my Mac and getting adjusted to Docker seems to be quite challenging and confusing.

A few weeks ago, I was able to mind port 8834 on the docker container to port 8834 on my local host by running the following commands (this is my command line history):

```
 8450  docker attach -p 8834:8834 compassionate_chandrasekhar
 8452  docker start -p 8834:8834 compassionate_chandrasekhar
```

Today, if I try to do the same thing, the following happens:

```
[user:test.local:]$ docker container ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
225146ec71d6        myuser/kali:kali   "/usr/bin/zsh"      9 minutes ago       Exited (0) 2 minutes ago                       agitated_fermat
e4389cac288a        myuser/kali:kali   "/usr/bin/zsh"      2 weeks ago         Exited (255) 2 weeks ago                       suspicious_hypatia
265f2c9215c5        myuser/kali:kali   "/usr/bin/zsh"      2 weeks ago         Exited (0) 2 weeks ago                         hungry_poincare
34b36b4d8a7e        myuser/kali:kali   "/usr/bin/zsh"      2 weeks ago         Created                                        amazing_stonebraker
```

followed by:

```
[user:test.local:]$ docker start -p 8834:8834 agitated_fermat
unknown shorthand flag: 'p' in -p
See 'docker start --help'.
```

What am I doing wrong? Extremely confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Publishing ports can be done only with newly created containers not existing containers. So you need to stop the container and create a new one with the port you need

Comment: Thanks. Was able to get this by exiting, and re-running it with `docker run -t -i -p 8834:8834 myuser/kali:kali /usr/bin/zsh`

Answer (score 1):

Today I was grabbing a Jenkins/Docker-tutorial, and got a similar error.

They do say to start the container the following way, but I got the same error as you:

```
docker run --name jenkinsci -p 8080:8080 jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

*=> "unknown shorthand flag: 'p' in -p"*

When I put the "name"-tag at the end I no longer get the error, and it downloads the container.

```
docker run -p 9090:8080 jenkins/jenkins:lts --name jenkinsci
```

It now tells me it does not recognize the option "--name"-tag after downloading.
Without "--name" the container runs.

(Tutorial link: https://medium.com/@gustavo.guss/quick-tutorial-of-jenkins-b99d5f5889f2)