# docker run reporting an error for port mapping

Tags: docker

I have installed Docker Desktop for Mac and I'm trying to run Jenkins in a docker container.

When I attempt to run the following command:

```
docker run --name jenkinsci -p 8080:8080 jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

the following error is reported:

```
unknown shorthand flag: 'p' in -p
```

I've been through [Get started with Docker Desktop for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/) successfully so I know docker is working correctly.

Docker version details:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.2
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        6247962
 Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:39 2019
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       6247962
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:13:06 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker doesn't recognize the -p command all of a sudden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54892812/docker-doesnt-recognize-the-p-command-all-of-a-sudden)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that somehow a non-space character got in between `run` and `--name`. I copied the string from a web page.

The above command does in fact work ok.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the running container before you change the port. You can see a quite similar post: [Docker doesn't recognize the -p command all of a sudden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54892812/docker-doesnt-recognize-the-p-command-all-of-a-sudden)

Comment: The container wasn't running.

Comment: Then put a space between `run` and `--name`